# PHP Change function to check multiple id's

Tags: php, function

I would like the below php functions to check for multiple product id's `!==` (1427, 1428, 1429).

I tried adding:

```
$ids = array(1427, 1428, 1429)
if (in_array($product->get_id(), $ids) { }
```

But it did not work.

What is the best approach?

Thank you.

```
//add multistep
add_action('wapf_before_wrapper', 'wapf_before_wrapper');
function wapf_before_wrapper($product) {
    if($product->get_id() !==1427)
                return;
    ?>
    <div class="wapf-progress">
        <div class="wapf-progress-bar"></div>
        <div class="wapf-progress-steps"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('wapf_before_product_totals', 'wapf_before_product_totals');
function wapf_before_product_totals($product){
    if($product->get_id() !==1427)
                return;
    ?>
    <div class="wapf_step_buttons">
        <button class="button wapf_btn_prev" style="display:none">Previous</button>
        <button class="button wapf_btn_next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <?php
} 
//end multistep
```

Comment: In your functions you're checking that `$product->get_id()` is NOT equal to the single id. Maybe you should use `!in_array()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the ````!==```` is correctly working. the ````!in_array()```` unfortunately crashed the script. Instead of 1 id "1427" I want to assign this function to multiple id's.

Comment: What does “crashed the script” mean, _exactly_? Also, show the code you actually tried.